# Can you connect a 14 gauge electrical wire with a 12 gauge?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, wire

In the attached image, the 14 gauge wire coming from the left and into the junction box, is from a gas stove the floor above. The 12 gauge wire coming from the right is connected to the panel and is no longer used. It would sure be convenient if I could just tie these two together instead of running wire all the way to the panel again. Is there anything wrong with connecting a 14 and 12 gauge together? The stove only requires 15amps so the 14 should be ok on that front:

[image: Wiring]

Answer (score 5):

You can do this, but you **must** make sure the breaker for the circuit is a 15A breaker, not a 20A breaker. It is also possible that someone in the future may look at the 12 gauge wire coming out of a 15A breaker and think "I can up that to 20A by just replacing the breaker", so labeling it properly on the panel is important.

Comment: That’s a great point (the future person looking at it). Perhaps I should just pull the 14ga wire out and feed down a 12 instead and connect them.

Comment: That is another option

Comment: It would be extremely irresponsible for anyone to "upgrade" the breaker based solely on the gauge of the wire connected to it. AWG12 is used all the time for longer 15A circuits, just to reduce the voltage drop.

Comment: @DaveTweed You are correct. But from a number of messages I have read on this site, people do stupid things and an ounce of prevention is worth a pound of cure.